# Jquery on click show and hide

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup

I am trying to create a jquery on click show and hide pop up.

I have managed to create the click and show but need to be able to make the pop up close when clicked on the dark bg.

Please see [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EtHbf/294/) here

```
$('#some-button').on('click', function () { 
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeIn(500); 
});
```

Comment: `$('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeToggle(500);` and `#some-button { position: relative; z-index: 100; }`

Comment: `$("div#overlay").click(function(){$(this).slideUp(); $("div#overlay-back").slideUp()});`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#some-button').on('click', function () {         
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeIn(500); 
    $("#overlay").on("click", function(){
      $("#overlay").off("click");
      $(".callme").off("click");
      $("#overlay, #overlay-back").fadeOut(500);  
    });
    $(".callme").on("click", function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your javascript:

```
 $("#overlay").on('click',function(){
     $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeOut(500); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Fadeout on overlay click

```
$('#some-button').on('click', function () { 
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeIn(500); 
});
// Fadeout
$('#overlay').on('click', function () { 
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeOut(200); 
});
```

Comment: need an `e.stopPropagation()` on the actual popup to prevent event triggering on clicks of an active area.

Comment: Hi, how would I add an close x in stead of the dark background close?

Comment: Add a button, and position it wherever you want it to be displayed on the screen, Now use the same method^ to close the div. for example:

`$('#button-id').on('click', function () { 
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeOut(200); 
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$('#overlay').on('click', function () { 
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeOut(500); 
});

$('.callme').on('click', function (e) { 
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EtHbf/298/)**

Answer (score 0):

Basically you add a click handler to the overlay and check to make sure the `.callme` div wasn't clicked, then hide the overlays.

```
$('#overlay').click(function(e){console.log(e);
    if ($(e.target).is(':not(.callme)')){
        $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeOut(500); 
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EtHbf/300/